# This is how I connect my Google instance VM to Cloud SQL/ And setup my Wordpress

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I've decided to move from normal hosting companies to Google cloud and run my own server; most of my websites are WordPress. but I want to make sure that what I've done is right .. its working until now! but not sure if it is the best thing to do;

I've created my VM instance;
I've installed vesta cpanel.

But for databases I dont want to host it in the same instance! so under the same project I've created SQL instance,

I connect it to my local MySql Workbench and its connected and worked.

then in Wordpress wp-config.php file

Username and Password used the same for my sql instance
host i change it from the localhost and used the public ip address for my sql instance

its connected! but i don't know if this is the best solution, I'm taking exactly about the hostname

Please let me know, all videos i've found on internet is talking about google app engine, why? why not just hosting the code on the VM instance and the database on SQL instance then link it togather using the ip address?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Google Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/), you can refer to this link that explains how to [connect MySQL client from Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine).
As you will noticed, you can connect using the IP address of your Cloud SQL instance or you can configure the Cloud SQL proxy, for a secure connection. Note that the proxy option is only available for 2nd generation instances.

If you have created a Google Compute Engine(GCE) instance and installed MySQL, the you can also use the IP of your GCE instance. If looking to setup a secure connection, then you will need to follow MySQL guidelines for [using secure connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html).